# Check collision 2D game, image/control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, 2d, collision

i'm developping a 2D Game for Windows Phone, for now i have a Xml parser that i used to config maps and draw items.

Maps are farms. My question is : Once i have all my items drawn, i d like to check collision. How can i define a control ( like a rectangle on my item ).

here the list of my items :

[image]

these items are store in a list with X and Y coords.

(I'm not using Xna, should I ?)
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not strictly necessary to use XNA, but if you're serious about learning game development on Phone/Windows/Xbox devices, it's a must.

Btw collision detection can mean multiple things. It may be based on distance or it may be based on shape intersection. For instance, you may define a shape that loosely surrounds a character, and another that (loosely?) surrounds a touchable item, or a tile, or a wall, then there is collision if those shapes intersect.

You can find info about collision detection algorithms everywhere, even on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection).

Good luck! But give that XNA a spin. It takes a while to get used to but every minute you invest in it pays itself back again and again.

Comment: I agree, for the most part, about XNA. However, be aware that MS is no longer updating the framework.

Comment: Thank you guys, I don't think I will dive into XNA cause its too deep for a beginner like me :) I understand about the shape around my items. but what is the shape ? a rectangle object ? or there is a method that surround my item ?

Comment: That's up to you to decide. You could take a rectangle, if that will do for your requirements, or a circle, or any shape that will fit so that 2 shapes only overlap when there is collision.